# Post text to a parent element with option to remove posted elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There are a few things I'd like help with. I have found pieces of the solution on stack overflow, but can't quite put it all together.

I'd want the user to add text to a text area, click a button to post the text to a parent element, and finally have the option to remove the posted text element from the parent. This is as far as I have gotten on the code. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<body>

<h4>A News Module.</h4>

<div id="container">
  <p>Here is some news.<a href="#" onclick="deleteNews()"></a></p>
</div>

<textarea id="alltext" rows="13" cols="53" placeholder="Add your news here."></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit News" onclick="addNews()">

<script>

    function addNews(){

      var addEl = document.createElement('p');

      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(addEl);
     }

    function deleteNews(){

      var deleteEl = document.getElementById('container');

      deleteEl.parentNode.removeChild(deleteEl);

     }

</script>
</body>
```

Also on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lotus89/nvo1s5re/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1) You need to add the text from the textboxt into the newly created element. Add the folowing line right after the creation:

`addEl.textContent = document.getElementById('alltext').value;`

This grabs the value of the texbox and sets it as the textContent of the newly created element.

2) `addNews()` needs to be in the global scope for jsfiddle
Add this line:

`window.addNews = addNews;`

**Edit**: Update fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rtj998gL/1/

Comment: Upvote. I answered similarly but you were a bit quicker than I was!

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at your `addNews` code. You're creating a new `p` and adding it to the container, but you're never putting anything *in* it.

   ```
   function addNews(){

     //Create blank P element
     var addEl = document.createElement('p');

     //Set the new element's content to match the textarea value
     addEl.innerHTML = document.getElementById("alltext").value;

     //Add it to the container
     document.getElementById('container').appendChild(addEl);

   }
   ```
2. If you put your `<script>` in the head of your page, your code would work fine. But being that it's in the `<body>`, your functions are not being found because they are out-of-scope. You can adjust for this by doing `window.addNews = addNews` within your `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thank you, as well!